# MySQL: Multiple Inner Joins Producing Skewed Count

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables, `tb_orders`, `tb_tasks` & `tb_userconfig` which I am trying to query but it seems like when running the query with both inner join statements, the `COUNT()` is completely skewed however when trying to run the query with only one inner join statement everything seems to work (minus the one column I would be missing)

Example table structure:

**tb_orders**

```
| OrderedBy | OrderDate    |
|-----------|--------------|
| persona   | 29/6/21 0:00 |
| persona   | 29/6/21 0:00 |
| personc   | 29/6/21 0:00 |
| personb   | 29/6/21 0:00 |
```

**tb_userconfig**

```
| EmployeeName | Username |
|--------------|----------|
| Person A     | persona  |
| Person B     | personb  |
| Person C     | personc  |
```

**tb_tasks**

```
| AssigneeUser |
|--------------|
| Persom A     |
| Person B     |
| Person C     |
| Person B     |
```

Query:

```sql
SELECT T1.EmployeeName, T1.Username, Count(T2.OrderedBy) AS OrderCount, Count(T3.AssigneeUser) AS TaskCount
FROM tb_userconfig AS T1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT OrderedBy, OrderDate FROM tb_orders
    ) AS T2 on T1.Username = T2.OrderedBy
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT AssigneeUser FROM tb_tasks
    ) AS T3 on T1.EmployeeName = T3.AssigneeUser
GROUP BY T1.EmployeeName ORDER BY T1.EmployeeName
```

Desired result:

```
| EmployeeName | Username | OrderCount | TaskCount |
|--------------|----------|------------|-----------|
| Person A     | persona  | 2          | 1         |
| Person B     | personb  | 1          | 2         |
| Person C     | personc  | 1          | 1         |
```

Any ideas on why the statement would be resulting in skewed counts and not producing the desired result?

TIA

Comment: Can you add the _skewed_ result?

Comment: As it is your code it would return nothing because the ON clause in the 2nd join is wrong. It should be: `on T1.Username = T3.AssigneeUser`. Also, for this sample data the 2nd join is not needed. So, I guess this is not your actual code and you oversimplified your actual data. Post the code and sample data that are closer to what you have and explain why you need the 2nd join.

Comment: Your code returns an error because `sql_mode` defaults to have `only_full_group_by` (in MySQL 8.0+), see [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8822152c17723e82cc76859a4bb5013c), which also includes the change @forpas is suggesting, and a simplification on how to do JOINs

Comment: @Luuk thanks for the fiddle, please check out this one (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=959d8b97434a8716360aa19e24c9a277). I have removed personc from tb_tasks which causes the result counts to be scewed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify by pre-aggregating the counts.

Without knowing your data I would suggest using outer joins and coalesce to handle no rows as otherwise users with tasks but no orders or vice-versa would be excluded.

```
select uc.EmployeeName, uc.username,
  Coalesce(o.OrderCount, 0) OrderCount, 
  Coalesce(t.TaskCount, 0) TaskCount
from tb_userconfig uc
left join (
  select orderedby, Count(*) OrderCount
  from tb_orders
  group by orderedby
) o on o.orderedby=uc.username
left join (
  select AssigneeUser, Count(*) TaskCount
  from tb_tasks
  group by AssigneeUser
) t on t.AssigneeUser=uc.username
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=387c23363c15e22e165a3e58fc1a1a3e)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however when I try and run it, it seems that the ```OrderCount``` is being populated however the TaskCount is ```0``` for all users... Any ideas?

Comment: Please take a look at this DB Fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6c907383f855fbd12e2d3b835a1c73d1

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are referring to, the query above is not even in your Fiddle. When I use the query in my answer [in your fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=462124f6045c504de4a4998a654bcbb0) there are no zeros

Comment: Thank you, seems like I was doing something funky but your query definitely works! Thanks for your help!